# What is UITableViewCell identifier's role when I create UITableView programmatically?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

Previously when I create a UITableView using storyboard, I set the cell identifier in property inspector and paste it into method `cellForRowAtIndexPath`, then use method `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier` to create a new UITableViewCell. However, when I create a UITableView programmatically, I have nowhere to set up cell identifier. I mean, I can arbitrarily appoint an identifier without having to match that in the property inspector. Am I right? And how should I create a UITableViewCell under this situation?

Comment: You want to create a UITableviewcell XIB or that also you want to do programmatically?

Comment: @Caesar [self.tableView registerClass:[UITableViewCell class]  forCellReuseIdentifier:CELLREUSE_IDENTIFIER]; in viewDidLoad or somewhere you think it's appropriate

Comment: @KiranJasvanee Also programmatically.

Comment: @Allen So the CELLREUSE_IDENTIFIER is arbitrary? And I should add this code only when I create them programmatically or also in Interface Builder?

Comment: To handle the dequeueing of cells to added to the view.

Comment: @Caesar CELLREUSE_IDENTIFIER is the place for you to put cell identifier. It's only necessary to register when you create them programmatically.

Comment: @MrWaqasAhmed Get it. So I can set up an arbitrary identifier?

Comment: @Allen Ah so you mean I need to keep the cellIdentifier I set in `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier ` matching to the CELLREUSE_IDENTIFIER?

Comment: Hi, if you want I give the answer how you can create UITableview and UITableviewCell both programmatically

Comment: @KiranJasvanee Indeed I wonder how to set the cell identifier when I create both of them programmatically. But if you like you can post the code that set both of them first :)

Comment: okay. let me post code with output

Comment: @Caesar Yes, you are right. "dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier matching to the CELLREUSE_IDENTIFIER"

Comment: Ok. I get it. Thanks~

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create UITableview and UITableviewCell both programmatically as below.

Create Tableview Programmatically,

```
@interface ViewController () <UITableViewDataSource>{
     //create tableview instance
     UITableView *tableViewPro;
}
```

Alloc it in viewDidLoad

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    // init table view
    tableViewPro = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds style:UITableViewStylePlain];

    // must set delegate & dataSource, otherwise the the table will be empty and not responsive
    tableViewPro.dataSource = self;

    tableViewPro.backgroundColor = [UIColor cyanColor];

    // add to canvas
    [self.view addSubview:tableViewPro];
}
```

Assign number of rows and UITableview cell in Tableview datasource methods

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{
    return 10;
}
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{


    static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"Tableviewcell";

    // Similar to UITableViewCell, but
    TableViewCell *cell = (TableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {
        //initialize uitableviewcell programmatically.
        cell = [[TableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    }
    // Just want to test, so I hardcode the data
    cell.descriptionLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Testing index %ld",(long)indexPath.row];

    return cell;
}
```

Now, create your UITableviewCell programmatically. First Add New->file->Cocoa Touch class->Enter tableviewcellname with subclass-of UITableviewCell and UNCHECK the 'Also create XIB file', because cell will be created programmatically.
Two files will be created .h and .m of UITableviewCell, I've create UITableviewCell with TableViewCell name. below is the code to achieve it programmatically.

```
@interface TableViewCell : UITableViewCell

@property (nonatomic,retain) UILabel *descriptionLabel;

@end
```

Synthesize descriptionLabel in @implementation file of TableViewCell

```
@synthesize descriptionLabel = _descriptionLabel;
```

Below is the initialization function function of creating a UITableviewCell Programmatically. ADD THIS FUNCTION ON @implementation file of TableViewCell

```
- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier
{
    //it will create UITableiviewCell programmatically and assign that instance on self.
    self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
    if (self) {
        // configure control(s)
        self.descriptionLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(5, 10, 300, 30)];
        self.descriptionLabel.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
        self.descriptionLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial" size:12.0f];

        [self addSubview:self.descriptionLabel];
    }
    return self;
}
```

Below is the resulted output.
[image]

Comment: Don't I need to call `registerClass:forCellReuseIdentifier:` first, as Allen said in his comment?

Comment: **self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];** - It's added in **initWithStyle** function in @implementation of UITableviewCell, and **initWithStyle** has been called from **cellForRowAtIndexpath** to register it.

Comment: UITableviewCell created programmatically, so it won't be registerclass:forCellReuseIdentifier it will be initWithStyle:reuseIdentifer.

Comment: It's a full pro grammatical way, you have to understand it. try it by preparing demo. It's totally reusable cells.

Comment: Typically, you *do* call registerClass:forCellReuseIdentifier: before instantiating. That way, the table will always deliver a cell and set it up for you.

Comment: Yeah I know that I just first create a new UITableViewCell using `cell = [[TableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier1];` and use reusable cells by `TableViewCell *cell = (TableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier2];` afterwards. So you mean I just need to keep cellIdentifier1 equal to cellIdentifier2? And when should I use `registerclass:forCellReuseIdentifie`?

Comment: **initWithStyle:reuseIdentifier:** will register your cell. you don't have to call **registerclass:forCellReuseIdentifier** - its an alternate way to register reusable cell